# Using reactive search with multiple indexes, but they don't all have the same data fields

Tags: javascript, reactivesearch

I am using ReactiveSearch and the CategorySearch component. I have multiple indexes I am searching against. I need about about 8 or so dataFields. However, some of the indexes don't have the same data fields. This ends up just giving me an empty result set even though my search term does exist in at least one of the indexes.

```
<ReactiveBase app="*" url={elasticSearch}>
        <CategorySearch
          componentId="searchbox"
          dataField={[
            'docId',
            'name',
            'email',
             ...
          ]}
```

If I remove all dataFields except docId, and name I am able to search across indexes.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you share a code sandbox where this happens?

Comment: @sidi Do you mean create sample project to recreate the issue? If so, I'll do that over the weekend. I take it, in theory this should be working?

Comment: I think it should work. Essentially, need to look into the ES query that is generated, a codesandbox would help in seeing the request in the network tab.